# Have anyone succeeded in ThinApp'ing Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, virtualization

The purpose is to have a USB flash to have a developer seat everywhere. The idea is to use application virtualization to package Visual Studio.

However, AFAIK, there are big problems.

Have anyone succeeded in packaging Visual Studio (2010, 2008) using ThinApp, App-V, ...

P.S. I'm aware of google.

Comment: Are you a masochist with way too much time on his hands? ;-) The answer is no, it is not practically possible to 'thinapp' visual studio. I don't have the will to enumerate the reasons why, but I am sure someone will.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible.  There's nothing "thin" about Visual Studio, it has an enormous mass of files in many different directories and a very large number of critical registry entries.  Including many COM components.  That it works as well as it does is one of the modern day's Seven World Wonders of software engineering.

Your license allows you to install VS on more than one machine as long as only one user uses it.  I recommend you take advantage of it.

Comment: _...it has an enormous mass of files in many different directories and a very large number of critical registry entries_.   
.  
Sounds like a great reason to try and virtualize it :)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to install Visual Studio 2013 in App-V, it takes a lot of time to load and takes about 3Gb in .dat file. Compiling and debugging in C++ tested and works but really slow. No errors or popups for missing components so far. After experimenting I made a final virtualization script that works. p.m me.

Comment: this is not the correct place to ask a question, you can only answer on others question,and do read FAQ before answering any question.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to make Visual Studio portable version using VMWare Thinapp. No installation will be needed for Visual Studio, .net Framework or any other dependency. It works with Visual Studio Express edition 2008 as I have experimented but for version 2010, it say "Invalid Licence Data. Reinstall...". If you find a way, please tell me!