# how to make the Delphi debugger work fine in virtualized Delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, virtualization

I'm trying to virtualize Delphi 2009.
One major problem is that the debugger doesn't work properly.
With VMWare ThinApp it doesn't know that I closed the program.
With Spoon Studio it gives random errors.
I tried on their forums and Embarcadero forums. Nobody knows a solution.

I hope you can help me...

Thank you.

Comment: It's probably related to ThinApp, because all Delphi products work absolutely fine on all versions of VmWare Workstation. Why exactly would you want to package Delphi 2009 as a ThinApp? That sounds like something Embarcadero would do! Ie: ThinApp is something you use *for your own app* to make distributing it easy.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund Probably... I'm virtualizing all big programs on my computer (like Office or Delphi) so my OS could run smoothly. I already noticed how well my OS is running without Office and I wanted to try also with Delphi.

Comment: Good luck. The more layers you add between your apps and the OS, the more issues and bugs you can introduce.

Comment: @ldsandon That's obvious. Anyway I have only one "layer" between them and I don't intend to add more...

Comment: @John, virtualizing Delphi that way is not a good idea. You're writing code, you need to do it in a realistic environment. Unless your users are going to use your applications in an ThinApp environment, you're just asking for trouble. And I will not tell you why virtualizing Office that way is also a bad idea, since this is Stack Overflow, not Super User.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund But not a bad idea also. It depends on what kind of programs you develop. For my programs is fine. Oh, and the environment is only partly virtual, not like in VMWare Workstation or VirtualBox.   I'm curious why you think that virtualizing Office is not good - if you don't wanna say here, just tell me how I can talk to you about this...

Comment: Virtualizing Office using ThinApp is a good way of paying a *lot* extra money to get *less* features. You can't install OEM Office in a VM and I guess you also need an extra Windows *retail* license. You pay all that to get less performance and no Explorer integration. Put a quarter of that money into extra RAM and your performance problems with Office installed are all gone. About programming, it doesn't matter what *kind* of programs you make but for *what platform*. It's always best to develop on a realistic platform. For me that's Windows 7 with UAC *enabled*.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund First, I don't spend my money, the company where I work is paying. I don't think that there are so many users with OEM Office and I don't think that you need a "extra Windows retail license" since the virtual environment is not Windows. Yes, the virtualized application has less performance but not by so much (5..10% max). Same with RAM. Having the OS finally "liberated" is worth it, imho. And I'm not the only one who thinks that, I found many others with the same opinion.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund Windows 7 with UAC is good. Anyway from time to time I can start the application in the real computer. And, by the way, when I test my applications, I do it on many more (real) computers, not just one. Anyway, these days I noticed that you know a lot of good things and I value your opinion but you're not 100% right, sorry to say that.

Comment: "the environment is only partly virtual, not like in VMWare Workstation or VirtualBox" that's even worse. At least full virtualization means applications still run directly on the OS. This way you put a layer between the app and the OS, something both are not designed for. While issues and bugs are always additive.

Comment: :) Here is a perfect example about taking small "truths" and combining them into something that resembles "a lot of truth" - but here you can't use '+'. When you have 10 x 10% truth that doesn't mean that you have 100%, it's still 10%. It's like I hear someone: don't ever go outside the house, you'll end up in a car accident, robbed, shot... Apparently he's right but he omits to say that there's very little chance that it will happen.

Comment: And another thing: I see that the people who are writing in these comments are not reading all that others are writing, interested only in their arguments. I have enough of these in real life, I don't need them in the "virtual" one. So, goodbye and have a nice day. I won't enter here anymore.

Comment: People writng questions like this should understand how deeply a debugger has to interact with the underlying OS to work properly. Those virtualization tools may be unfit for the task, they may not be designed for dev tools. And IMHO your issues are products issues, you should try to resolve them with the product supplier. If you pay, you should also have support beyond forums, right? Or are you going to deploy that way without support?

Comment: Others have faced this problem, trying to get Visual Studio to work as a "thin app": [vmware forum link](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/185827) and [stack overflow link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501376/have-anyone-succeeded-in-thinapping-visual-studio). The SO link provides a possible solution, using Microsoft's "App-V".

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Windows 7 in the guest and seeing errors along the lines of "Assertion failure: "(!SetThreadContext failed")", then [Hotfix 2](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/27476) might help you.